# need help wpf app need the sum of 5 boxes

Tags: c#, wpf

heeey everyone im new to wpf and i need some help i've been trying the internet but no luck so i thought i would ask here since u help alot of people here...

my project is to make a program that can find the sum of 5 different boxes but the problem is i dont know how to use the math function to make it understand that it needs to sum the boxes hope u understand what i mean...

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double output1 = double.Parse(Txtbox1.Text) + double.Parse(Txtbox2.Text);


        Result.Text = output1.ToString();



    }
```

xaml

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="102*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="127*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="147*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="141*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="43*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="Txtbox1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131"/>
        <TextBox Name="Txtbox2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131"/>
        <TextBox Name="Txtbox3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <TextBox Name="Txtbox4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <TextBox Name="Result" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="7" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Comment: So what's your question? You have it summing two text boxes, you just need to extend it to include the other two. Of course, this is far from the most robust way to do. Better would be to have a model that is bound to your view that would update the total as the components change.

Comment: The problem is that it should sum the up but nothing actually happen when i run the program... and yeah its something like that im looking for something that makes its update constant

Comment: You've hooked the `TextChange` event of `Result`, not the `TextChange` of the `Txtbox1`, `Txtbox2`, `Txtbox3`, and `Txtbox4`. It's when they change that you want to update the total. Not when the result changes (which ought to be set to read-only anyway)

Comment: its kinda working now but the result only shows up when i try to write a number in the result box :S

Comment: Stop all that you're doing. Search WPF MVVM and learn MVVM *before* you try to do anything in wpf. You're going down a slippery slope with your current approach and it's going to get very painful very quick.

Comment: Try to learn WPF binding. WPF has its own way to do the stuff. After playing with binding you will do such stuff very easily. Check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm

Comment: I hardly recommend to get used to MVVM

Comment: thanks alot that tutorial helped alot

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is fine, but you need to trigger the calculation correctly.

You currently handle the `TextChanged` event of the *result*, but you really need to trigger on the inputs.

You can do this in several ways:

1. Move your event handler to the input boxes, or
2. Use a `Command` on the input boxes, or
3. Bind the inputs to properties of a view model, and have their setters update the output (you'll need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this).

If none of that makes sense, then you'll just have to take some time to study more WPF.